# Granting access to IBM Blockchain 2.0

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-blockchain

trying to grant access to an IBM Blockchain 2.0 instance to another user. The access policies look like:

[image: What am I missing?]

But the user gets this error message:

[image]

What am I missing? Something obvious?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: (Yes - I know I've got basically the same service added twice.) Was poking around the UI to see if there was something I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add their IBM Cloud ID to your users list in the 2.0 Platform UI, assigning access policies is not necessary.

Update: IBP 2.0 access is now managed by IAM. Follow the guides for granting appropriate permissions to access the Console

Comment: Yes, this was what was missing. Do I still need to set Access Policies in IAM then?

Comment: Looks like an update was released about a week after this that now requires access to be managed via IAM.

Comment: @ayang I've edited my original post to include this info, thanks!

Comment: actually, I have opened a new ticket - which is my original question. I am trying to assign privileges in IAM but nothing is working. In fact, the owning user no longer has access either (even though I didn't change anything for that userid). Effectively, the error message is telling the user to request access from themselves. 

The documentation link is useful, but doesn't seem to work. Is the configuration in the original question invalid? Is there some conflict there that is invalidating all grants?